# How to translate strings in javascript written in script tags of html in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Hi I am translating a website in hungarian, I have problems with alerts and confirm strings that i have in my templates. I am using `gettext('')` but these strings are not appearing in po files

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
   url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
```

I have created po file django.po by running makemessages it has all the strings marked as trans in templates and also strings from `*.py` files.
then
I have run following command

```
django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l hu_HU
```

its creating `djangojs.po`.

The strings appearing in this file are all from *.js files in my static folder.

But how do i have my strings used in alerts and confirms that are written in my templates.

here are snippets from my templates.

```
<script>
    if($('#id_action').val()=='DEL'){
        if(confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to delete selected author(s) ?'))){
           flag_action=true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my template i also have something like this which is not appearing in po files either.

```
<li>
   <a onclick="if(confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to delete the selected author?'))){filter_content({{auth.id}},'DEL');return false;}" href="javascript:void(0)">
      {% trans 'Delete' %}
   </a>
</li>
```

The string in gettext is not appearing in any po.

I have included the following in my templates

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use this

```js
var alert_var = {% blocktrans %}"Are you sure you want to delete selected author(s) ?" {% endblocktrans %};
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

> then use this variable where ever you need

Comment: Thank you, I have used trans instead of gettext it works but I am not sure how it will affect the performance of the site.Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

As Arhot said `{% blocktrans %}"Text..."{% endblocktrans %}` works perfectly.

If you use this inside the `<script>` tags in the html file, the words ids will be generated in the file `.po` corresponding to html traslations and not javascript traslations. I mean you will find the new words in the file `django.po` and not inside the `djangojs.po`.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I understand you might not have commenting rights yet, but answers are reserved strictly to answer the posed question - and nothing else. Great that you participate and thank you in the name of the community, but if someone checks this question they will definitely be bamboozled by this answer unless they read the comments carefully.